# how to track transition from circuit open to close to notify Devs?

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I have written custom event notifier and registered it in HystrixPlugins. I have requirement like need to send notifications when Circuit is opened and closed. To track circuit-open I can use below event type

```
 HystrixEventType.SHORT_CIRCUITED
```

but what about transition from Open to close? is there any way in hystrix to track  circuit is close now which was opened previously?.

Below is my Event notifier.

```
public class CircuitBreakerHystrixEventNotifier extends HystrixEventNotifier{

    @Resource
    private List<HystrixNotification> notificationHandlers;

    public CircuitBreakerHystrixEventNotifier(){

    }

    public void markEvent(HystrixEventType eventType, HystrixCommandKey key) {
        super.markEvent(eventType, key);
        if(notificationHandlers != null && notificationHandlers.size() > 0){
            for (HystrixNotification notificationHandler : notificationHandlers){
                notificationHandler.notify(eventType, key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find solution for this problem ? I could see that SUCCESS status denotes that circuit is closed - but its not possible to track when the switch happened from OPEN to CLOSED circuit.

Comment: Yes, I maintained one set of "OPNED circuits". 
if "Success" event come for particular circuit then check was that circuit opened(check presence of command key in Open circuits set  ).